# Infinite subset of a plane curve is dense.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, zariski-topology

I want to solve Fulton's Algebraic Curves book exercise 6.5.

> Any infinite subset of a plane curve $V$ is dense in $V$.

I looked for a solution here before asking and I found this:
[algebraic geometry exercise: infinite subset is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341813/algebraic-geometry-exercise-infinite-subset-is-dense). However, I didn't understand that answer  (sorry if you consider this to be a duplicate) and asked my teacher for some hints. He told me to think only about irreducible curves and use the properties of Zariski topology.

This is what I thought:

$V=\mathrm V (F)$ is an algebraic set, therefore a closed set. Let $\emptyset \neq U\subseteq V$ be an infinite subset. If we find that $U$ is open, then it is dense in the Zariski topology.

I think I have to prove that $U^c$ is closed. It would be straightforward if the complementary of the infinite subset is a finite subset, because every point is a closed set and finite intersection of closed sets is closed. But I don't know if it can be that the complementary is an infinite subset too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\subseteq V$ be the closure of an infinite subset of $V$. Then by definition of Zariski topology $X$ is the set of zeros of a finite number of polynomials. Take one of these polynomials, it defines an algebraic set which is a finite union of points and curves. Each of these curves either intersects $V$ in a finite number of points, or is equal to $V$ (this must have been shown in the previous chapter). So we see that either $X$ is finite or $X$ contains $V$, and so is dense.

See prop. 2 on page 18.

Comment: What happens if $V$ is an irreducible curve? I don't know why my teacher told me to think about irreducible curves.